# Logical replication stops

Tags: transactions, replication, long-integer

I have built logical replication for the two server instances. There 105 tables in each server and two databases, All tables are same. I built logical replication for 50 tables and then another 50. First fifty working perfectly, but second fifty stops working after some time. I checked and found out that amount of transaction is happening in the second 50 tables is high. That is the reason why second 50 tables stops. I doubt that it can be related to long running transactions maybe. If someone has experienced this kind of problem give me clue. I would appreciate it.